# The queries on symfony4 / twig

Tags: php, twig, symfony4

I started on symfony4 some time ago but every time I hang on to something. In fact I'm trying to do the action on my code and have a result that is on the image, but I do not know how to do it in symfony4 / twig ... If you have an idea thank you for to have given me my hands.

An example of what I want to do:

```
foreach($connexao->mostrarDadosCategoria() as $data)
{

    echo  $data->getCategoria() //afficher la categorie du film (ex: Action)

    //Afficher les films par categorie
    foreach($connexao->mostrarDadosPreparadoFilme($data->getCategoria()) as $data)
    {
            echo  $data->getTitulo_filme(); // le film (ex: Mission impossible fallout)
            echo  $data->getDescricao(); //la description
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Post code as text. Then read symfony manual, maybe several times.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is good that you posted a link with the code example, but you must post the relevant piece of code in the answer itself, so it will not depend on link's availability. I recommend reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), there you will find this is a requirement for a good question, among other good guidelines. You can also find more useful information about how StackOverflow works in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Have you tried reading the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html)? Twig is very easy to use, but you do have to spend some at lest some effort to learn it.

Comment: thanks @ehymel, i've just found the solution in twig docs, in fact it were missing a if statement in my loop for. someting like {% for user in users if user.active %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do a for loop with Twig https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```html
{% for data in connexao.mostrarDadosCategoria() %}
    {{ data.categoria }} //afficher la categorie du film (ex: Action)
    //Afficher les films par categorie
    {% for data in connexao.mostrarDadosPreparadoFilme(data.dategoria) %}
      {{ data.titulo_filme }} // le film (ex: Mission impossible fallout)
      {{ data.Descricao }}  //la description
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

thanks